# Encoding JMP FAR and CALL FAR in x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, machine-code, instruction-encoding

I'm familiar with r/m8, r/m16, imm16, etc but how do I encode m16:16, m16:32, and m16:64?  These are in the JMP and CALL instructions...

Is m16:16 an address location?  Or is it like an immediate address?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"encode" would normally mean machine-code bytes.  But I think you're asking about assembler syntax, because Intel's manuals are clear about the machine code.  (See the entry for [`jmp`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html), or the rest of [Intel's vol.2 instruction set reference manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#three-volume) for more about how an entry is formatted and what stuff means.)

---

`jmp m16:64` is a memory-indirect far jump, with a new RIP and CS value (in that order because x86 is little-endian).

Just like a memory-indirect near jump, you simply supply an addressing mode, and the CPU loads the memory operand from there.  But it's a 10-byte memory operand instead of 8 for a near jump.

You can use any addressing mode.  I used `[rdi]` for simplicitly.  All of this would be the same with `call far` / `lcall` as well.

NASM syntax:

```
jmp far [rdi]        ; for YASM, you need a manual REX prefix somehow
```

AT&T syntax:

```
rex64 ljmp *(%rdi)        # force REX prefix which buggy GAS omits
ljmpq *(%rdi)             # clang accepts this, GAS doesn't.
```

GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` disassembly for `objdump -drwC -Mintel:

```
  400080:       48 ff 2f        rex.W jmp FWORD PTR [rdi]
```

Or from `llvm-objdump -d` into AT&T syntax:

```
  400080:  48 ff 2f             ljmpq   *(%rdi)
```

**GNU Binutils wrong**, it needs a `48` REX.W prefix to set the operand-size to 64-bit.  (Of the memory source operand, I think.)

FWORD (48-bit far-word = m16:32) might actually be correct disassembly without a REX prefix, which is why it isn't what we want and why it crashes without a REX.W if the pointed-to memory is actually an `m16:64`.  We want `48 ff 2f` for a TWORD (m16:64) memory operand.

GAS won't assemble `ljmpq *(%rdi)`, but clang will.

---

**For example, to set CS=si and RIP=rdi**

```
; NASM syntax
mov   [rsp], rdi
mov   [rsp+8], si     ; new CS value goes last because x86 is little-endian
jmp far  [rsp]       ; loads 10 byte from memory
```

or `push rsi` / `push rdi` / `jmp far [rsp]`, or any other memory location you want to use.

---

NASM knows that a far jmp requires a REX.W prefix, unlike YASM and GNU Binutils.  It uses

```
; assembled by NASM (not YASM), disassembled with objdump -drwC -Mintel
400080:       48 ff 2f                rex.W jmp FWORD PTR [rdi]
```

`printf '\xff\x2f' | ndisasm -b64 -` shows us NASM's disassembly output:

```
; ndisasm -b64 output thinks it's a dword (m16:16)?
00000000  FF2F              jmp dword far [rdi]
```

**Intel's manual entry lists `jmp m16:64` as requiring a REX.W prefix**, but GAS / binutils incorrectly thinks that's not necessary.  See also discussion on https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/12/23/164 about Linux kernel code usage of `lret` vs. `rex64 ljmp *initial_code(%rip)`, and guesswork as to whether AMD CPUs support `FF /5` with a REX.W prefix.  Since AMD documentation doesn't explicitly mention it.

---

#### Experimental test: REX prefix needed for far jump/call

**I tested this** in a static-pie executable on GNU/Linux (so it would be loaded outside the low 32 bits), on an Intel i7-6700k Skylake:

```
default rel
foo:
    mov  eax, 231
    syscall              ; exit_group(edi)

global _start
_start:

    mov  eax, cs
    push rax             ; push cs is gone in x86-64
    lea  rax, [foo]
    push rax
    call far [rsp]
```

```
$ nasm -felf64 farjmp.asm          # or yasm
$ gcc -nostdlib -static-pie farjmp.o  -o farjmp
$ ./farjmp
or  gdb ./farjmp
```

- Assembled by YASM (with no REX.W), it segfaults on `call far [rsp]`.
- Assembled by NASM, (with a REX.W), it successfully reaches `foo:`

---

**`jmp far ptr16:64` doesn't exist, and `ptr16:32` or `ptr16:16` aren't usable in 64-bit mode**.  That would be a 10-byte immediate (direct) absolute jump target.  x86-64 can't use absolute direct jumps at all: there's no way to encode a new CS or RIP into a `jmp` instruction.

Direct near jumps use a `rel32` or `rel8`, and of course they can't change CS.  (That's what near means).

32-bit mode has `jmp far ptr16:32` (with a 6-byte immediate).

There aren't many use-cases for `jmp far`, especially in 64-bit mode.  In a kernel, you'd use `iret` or `sysret` to return to 32-bit user-space, and there's usually no other reason to switch code segments.  I guess you could have your kernel switch to 32-bit mode within the kernel.

Comment: The intel manual says both of the JMP far ptr16:16 and JMP far ptr16:32 are not available in 64-bit mode.  I'm just using 64-bit to make things easier. It says m16:16, m16:32 and m16:64 are all available though...  The near jumps don't have to specify anything other than the offset as far as I can tell??  How the heck do I encode that CS value?  Also you can far jump using a register?  Or address?  So confused

Comment: @RyanBrown: Right, in 64-bit mode there are no direct far jumps.  The CS value doesn't go in the instruction stream, you store it in memory and use a memory-indirect jump.  like `mov [rsp], rdi` / `mov [rsp+8], si` / `jmp far [rsp]` to do CS=si and RIP=rdi.  (There are no register-indirect far jumps, because `cs:rip` doesn't fit in a single GP register).  You're right that the manual lists `jmp m16:32` as encodeable in 64-bit mode, so maybe you do need REX.W for a normal `m16:64`.  Or else the manual is wrong.

Comment: So JMP m16:64 means I have to use a label that I defined earlier (CS)?  Is it used to jump to other programs?  Damn this is complicated!  Also the far JMP 16 and 32 use the same op-code, how do I differentiate them?

Comment: Also I have a quick question.  Is Call used frequently or do you manually use the stack functions instead?

Comment: ok last question... is m16:64 the same as m16:r/m64?  or is it memory address only?

Comment: @RyanBrown: what, no.  segment selectors index into the GDT or LDT, not labels.  If you just want to jump to a label, you only need to change RIP, not CS; just use a near jump.  Like `jmp my_label`, and let the assembler calculate the rel32 for you.  Or put an absolute address in a register and `jmp rax`.  As for `jmp m16:32` in 64-bit mode, the ISA manual doesn't show prefixes other than REX.  In this case it might be a mistake in the manual, but if you look at `add`, `add r16, r/m16` is the same opcode as `add r32, r/m32`.  in 32 or 64-bit mode, use a `66` operand-size prefix.

Comment: Yes, `call`/`ret` is the most efficient way to implement functions.  Look at compiler-generated code if you don't know what "normal" code looks like.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) has a good introduction, especially the video of Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk.